# lookup unique text values with criteria

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Dear all please suggest the formula...

```
cheque date tr code amount  realised on         
1/Jan/2011  164845  1000    1/Jan/2011      
1/Jan/2011  154375  2000    1/Jan/2011      
1/Jan/2011  164328  5000    1/Jan/2011      
1/Jan/2011  268543  3000    5/Jan/2011      
1/Jan/2011  547653  5000    5/Jan/2011      
1/Jan/2011  754975  5475    5/Jan/2011      
5/Jan/2011  164375  7000    5/Jan/2011      
5/Jan/2011  553865  5333    7/Jan/2011      
5/Jan/2011  642864  5000    7/Jan/2011      
7/Jan/2011  653754  4000    7/Jan/2011      
7/Jan/2011  764286  5754    7/Jan/2011      
7/Jan/2011  753975  4678    7/Jan/2011      
7/Jan/2011  653875  5477    7/Jan/2011      
7/Jan/2011  763975  6478    7/Jan/2011      
7/Jan/2011  764975  5377    8/Jan/2011      
7/Jan/2011  648763  5484    8/Jan/2011
```

result

```
1/Jan/2011      5/Jan/2011      7/Jan/2011  
tr code amount  tr code amount  tr code amount
```

result of date 1/jan/2011 should show the transaction code and amount if the realisation date if greater than 01/jan/2011

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that

1. The four columns in your sample data are columns A:D
2. The result data are in columns F:G for Jan 1, 2011 and in further pairs of columns for other dates.
3. the dates in your result sheet are in row 1

then you would need this formula in the "tr code" column (F), row 3.

'=IF($D3=F$1, $B3,"")`

The formula in G3 would only be very slightly different:-

`=IF($D3=F$1, $C3,"")`

Select the range F3:G3 and copy to the left and down as far as required.

If the original data and the results aren't on the same sheet, adapt the formulas to fetch data from the data sheet.

If you don't need the blank rows, copy / paste values and sort each pair of columns.